# Filtering array in monoTouch with NSPredicate

Tags: c#, iphone, ios, xamarin.ios

So I'm trying to filter an array with NSPredicate in MonoTouch. In Objective-c it would be something like this:

```
NSPredicate *findStringWithReference = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF CONTAINS [cd] %@",cRText.text];
NSArray *trackTraceContentFiltered = [trackTraceContent filteredArrayUsingPredicate:findStringWithReference];
```

I can't figure out how to do this in c#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have to use an NSArray or could you use a .Net List / Collection enabling you to use Linq?

[101 LINQ Samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b) is a great resource for using LINQ.

Comment: Everything that works should do. I'm just used to objective-c. I think .net would be better for shared code.

Comment: Yeah if you are planning to do anything which is shared across platforms then stick to straight c#.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
NSPredicate findStringWithReference = NSPredicate.FromFormat("SELF CONTAINS [cd] %@", new NSObject[] {cRText.StringValue } );
var trackTraceContentFiltered = trackTraceContent.Filter(findStringWithReference);
```

If you are working in .NET, you can use LINQ. There are lots of examples online, something like this:

```
var array = new string[] { "one", "two", "three" };
var filteredResult = array.Where(x => x.Contains("ne");
```

Comment: Error CS1061: Type `MonoTouch.UIKit.UITextField' does not contain a definition for `StringValue' and no extension method `StringValue' of type `MonoTouch.UIKit.UITextField'

______________________________________________________________________


Error CS1061: Type `System.Array' does not contain a definition for `Filter' and no extension method `Filter' of type `System.Array' could be found

Comment: You didn't define where the text value for your filter was coming from. And, no, you can't use a NSPredicate on a .NET array.